# Widgets placement

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place two `Entry` widgets in the center of the window (`hour_en` and `min_en`) and above them two `Label` widgets (`hour_lbl` and `min_lbl`) respectively but I can't get it. I would prefer `grid()` rather than `pack()` .

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import tk

window=Tk()
window.configure(bg='#10100f')
window.geometry("200x100")
window.resizable(False, False)

hour_lbl =Label(window,text="Hour")
hour_lbl.pack(side =TOP)
min_lbl = Label(window, text="Min")
min_lbl.pack(side=TOP)
hour_en = Entry(window, width=4)
hour_en.pack(side=LEFT,padx=(65, 0))
min_en = Entry(window, width=4)
min_en.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(10, 0))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you prefer `grid` over `pack`, why have you used `pack` and why haven't you tried `grid`? There is a lot of information about how to use `grid`, and all of it's options are documented.

Comment: You better put the labels and entries in a frame and it is easier to center a frame than a group of widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To arange the widgets use the grid geometry manager, there is excelent documentation like already mentioned. For example [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html).

Place the 4 widgets in a frame so you can later simply center the frame and therefore the group of widgets in it (like suggested in the comments).

With the changes your code could look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.configure(bg='#10100f')
window.geometry("200x100")
window.resizable(False, False)

center_frame = Frame(window)

Label(center_frame, text="Hour").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(center_frame, text="Min").grid(row=0, column=1)

Entry(center_frame, width=4).grid(row=1, column=0)
Entry(center_frame, width=4).grid(row=1, column=1)

center_frame.pack(anchor='center', expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```